# Wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

```
Create or replace procedure sp_create_tables as 
Lv_str varchar2(1000);
Begin
    For I in (select distinct(deptno) from emp) loop
    Lv_str:='create table deptno'||I||'  select * from emp where 
        1=2';
    Execute immediate lv_str;
    End loop;
End;
```

Comment: Hi Prasanth, I see that you show your effort but you need to explain clearly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

In this line of code `I` is an implicit **rowtype** variable, with a data structure defined by the projection of the driving select statement:

```
For I in (select distinct(deptno) from emp) loop
```

But you are attempting to reference it in your dynamic SQL as though it were an attribute. You need to use a column name instead.

```
Create or replace procedure sp_create_tables as 
   Lv_str varchar2(1000);
Begin
    For I in (select distinct (deptno) from emp) loop
        Lv_str:='create table deptno'|| I.deptno ||
              ' as  select * from emp where  1=2';
        Execute immediate lv_str;
    End loop;
End;
```

Incidentally there is a bug in your dynamic SQL statement. The correct syntax is `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`. Dynamic SQL is hard because the compiler can't validate the bits of code in strings. Consequently what should be compilation errors manifest themselves as runtime errors. You will find it helpful to instrument your code with some logging (or `dbms_output.put_line()`) to record the assembled statement before it runs. It makes debugging a lot easier.

---

> " i have got a error saying -01031 insufficient priviliges"

So what this means is your authorisation to create a table was granted through a role. The Oracle security model does not allow us to build PL/SQL programs - or views - using privileges granted through a role. This includes PL/SQL executing DDL through dynamic SQL. You need a DBA user to grant CREATE TABLE to your user directly.

Comment: it was helpful but i have got a error saying -01031 insufficient priviliges

Answer (score 4):

From what I can understand, your question is probably "why the procedure throws this compilation error"

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

The reason is that the implicit cursor loop variable `I` refers to the set of records from the query and not the deptno itself. In order to refer to the deptno, you should use `<loop_variable>.deptno`. Also 2 other things you should change: The `as` keyword is missing and `DISTINCT` is a keyword and you are using it as a function, which works because of default parentheses, but is not the right way to use it.

```
Create or replace procedure sp_create_tables as 
Lv_str varchar2(1000);
Begin
    For I in (select distinct dept from emp) loop
    Lv_str:='create table deptno'||I.deptno||' as select * from emp where 
        1=2';
    Execute immediate lv_str;
    End loop;
End;
```